# HTTPS is set up for aws Nodejs elastic beanstalk throught ACM and load balancer, how do i set up the HTTPS for angular in s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new with aws and web dev. I am running nodejs on elastic beanstalk and angular7 on s3. How do i get angular 7 to load SSL certificate from the one generated by Amazon Certificate manager?

Comment: Do you need to do this ? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cloudfront.
ACM only integrates with a few services: Elastic Beanstalk, ELB,  Cloudfront, API Gateway and Cloudformation.
As per the AWS documentation, you need to create a Cloudfront distribution, install your certificate in there using ACM, and point the distribution to your S3 static website.
Later you can point your Route53 domain to your cloudfront distribution to use your own domain.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: Doesn't this just encrypts the S3 data, how about the request made to the elastic beanstalk? I did it and got the web page to be https but the requests to the elastic beanstalk server areinsecure, " requested insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint"

Comment: in that case you need to load the certificate in elastic beanstalk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html